# Update table row based on selected combobox item

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

I have three classes: Super_Seller, Seller and Customer.
Each Super_Seller has a list of sellers and each Seller has a list of customers.
I have two jsp files:

1. AAA.jsp contains three comboboxes:

   a) First combobox: contains the list of the super sellers.

   b) Second combobox: contains the list of sellers according to the selected super seller.

   c) Third combobox: contains the list of customers according to the selected seller.
2. BBB.jsp contains a table.
   This table fills according to the selected combobox.
   If we select an element of first combobox, we display in the table the list of its sellers. And if we select an element of second combobox, we display the list of its customers.

Below some code in AAA.jsp to initiate combobox and load data.

```
function initCombobox(comboboxEl, profile){
$(comboboxEl).kendoComboBox({
  suggest: true,
  index: 0,
  dataSource: [],
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id"
});
var combobox = $(comboboxEl).data("kendoComboBox");
if(profile == 'SUPER_SELLER') {
    combobox.input.attr("placeholder", chooseSuperSellerPlaceholder);
    //combobox.dataSource.add({name: "TOUT",id: "1"});
}
if(profile == 'SELLER') {
    combobox.input.attr("placeholder", chooseSellerPlaceholder);
}
if(profile == 'END_CUSTOMER') {
    combobox.input.attr("placeholder", chooseCustomerPlaceholder);
}

$(comboboxEl).on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).data("kendoComboBox").value();
    if(profile == 'SUPER_SELLER') {
        loadChildren('#h-seller', 'SELLER', val);
    }
    if(profile == 'SELLER') {
        loadChildren('#h-customer', 'END_CUSTOMER', val);
    }
    if(profile == 'END_CUSTOMER') {
        selectCustomer(val);
    }
});
}
```

Code for table in BBB.jsp:

```
<table id="dt_individual_search" class="uk-table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">ID</th>
                <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">Name</th>
                <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">Profile</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
                <c:forEach var="customer" items="${customers}">
                <tr id="c-row-${customer.id}">
                    <td class="uk-text-center">${customer.id}</td>
                    <td class="uk-text-center">${customer.name}</td>
                    <td class="uk-text-center">${customer.profile}</td>                                           
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
         </tbody>
     </table>
```

Please, how to do that using javascript, ajax, json?

Comment: Have you got some code - so that we can see how far you have got with this.

Comment: @RichardHousham ok thanks, I edited my post.